# Does every topic subscription imply a separate TCP connection?

Tags: solace

Does Solace support the idea of a client having multiple topic subscriptions that are multiplexed over a single tcp connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run multiple topic subscriptions over the same Solace session which connects to one Solace appliance's host and port. Most middleware providers implement this multiplexing however.